# How to set context to "it" block in mocha dynamically?( Similar to describe)

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

It block is not taking the context of describe block.

```js
for( var i =0 ;i< dynamicFunctions.length; i++){
  (function wrap(dynamicFunction){
    describe("condition", function(){
      // It is executing all functions sequentially one by one.
      // since it is executed before it
      dynamicFunction.apply(null)
      it("should execute", function(){
        // It is always executing last function of the array.
        // since dynamicFunction is referring to last element of the array.
        // how to executing all functions sequentially one by one
        // like how it executes outside it block
        dynamicFunction.apply(null);
      }
    })
  }(dynamicFunctions[i]));
}
```

How to run it with different functions like how it executes outside it block?

Comment: That looks like far too much logic inside your tests - and that always has a bad smell. What are you trying to achieve? Test-Call every function?

Comment: On calling different functions, properties of one single object changes. So I have to call those different functions with different arguments to check that single object.

Comment: Why dont you do this INSIDE a single test ( == it-block)?

Comment: I have only given the way for easy understanding. In reality I am handling much complex testing and this logic will be part of it. If I couldn't achieve this, it will complicate more. please help me in this.

Comment: This is exactly what i was saying: If your testing is COMPLEX, you are most certainly doing something wrong. Tests shouldnt be created dynamically at runtime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot able to access dynamic test values inside "it" function of mocha, though it is accessible inside "describe" function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828300/cannot-able-to-access-dynamic-test-values-inside-it-function-of-mocha-though)